# Configure IPython from jupyter_client.manager

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

How can i add configurations to start a kernel via `jupyter_client.manager.start_new_kernel()` without setting up a default configuration file in .ipython directory? I want to set shell colors to 'NoColor' without setting up a config file and initialize specific formatters.

This is equivalent to the following config file:

```
c = get_config()
c.InteractiveShell.colors = 'NoColor'
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked: manager.start_new_kernel(extra_arguments=["--colors='NoColor'"])